# how to open front camera and back camera at same time?

Tags: java, android, camera

```
int frontCameraId = getFrontCamera();
Camera fc = Camera.open(frontCameraId);

int backendCamera = getBackendCamera();
Camera bc = Camera.open(backendCamera);
```

`#bc == null`, so how to open at the same time？

is it possible to open camera at same time ?

Comment: No any answer helped you my friend? You should accept answer if helped so that other googler get efficient answers for their question..:)

Comment: If you found a solution, then also you should place it here. :)

Answer (score 7):

### First

You are not creating any new object of Camera explicitly. You are using **singleton** method of `Camera`. So there will be only one instance in memory.

### Second

In Android documentation, there is written that..

> Your application should only have one Camera object active at a time for a particular hardware camera.

So this will also tell us that, we can't use more then one objects of Camera at the same time.

### Conclusion

It is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

Galaxy S4 has introduced an advanced feature of using two cameras at the same time.

However, it is a SAMSUNG private technology. You can check if is included in the SDK extension of SAMSUNG.